# Can I integrate leak canary to AOSP build system?

Tags: android-source, leakcanary

Can i add leak canary aar to Android.mk dependency and use leak canary as part of system app

Answer (score 0):

You should try using android_library_import in Android.bp instead. Check some documentation in Soong Modules Reference.

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build#modules